# SQL HTML Code Converter/Formatter

Tags: html, sql, converters, formatter

I own a website where I like to store my favourite SQL scripts.

I have previously seen an online converter tool which formats SQL code to have the applicable html tags so that when viewing the site the colours of key words such as SELECT FROM WHERE are all blue as per SQL management studio.

It looks exactly like one of those translation websites where you copy in your text, hit convert then get an output.

Problem is I can't for the life of me find which tool I used!! Does anyone know of one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google returns a number of results.

- https://highlightjs.org/
- http://prismjs.com/
- https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/
- http://craig.is/making/rainbows

The point to note though is that you don't mark-up your code, the highlighter does it for you on the fly. You just need to flag in someway what language/syntax the highlighter needs to target.

Comment: Great thank you.

I did try google but only seemed to suggest how to output results sets into HTML. I think Mark-Up was the keyword I was missing.